# How do I disable resizable rows in a wxPython Grid?

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm using a [`wx.grid.Grid`](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.Grid-class.html) in my application. Its never going to be useful to resize the rows of the grid, so I would love to disable the ability to resize them. Is this possible, and how would I go about doing it?

#### Justification

When testing the application I keep accidentally clicking the surprisingly large border between cells when I'm trying to click the cell body. The rows can't be much more than 20px tall, and the clickable (draggable) border is at least 3px across. In addition to the fact that I often accidentally rescale a row when I intended to select multiple cells, I really think it's worth disabling resizing. An acceptable alternative would be to disable dragging of the borders between the cells entirely, but still enable resizing of rows and columns by the border between the labels along the top and left edge.

Comment: Is [DisableDragRowSize()](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.Grid-class.html#DisableDragRowSize) what you need?

Comment: @SamMussmann: Yes! Absolutely perfect! Put it in an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[DisableDragRowSize()](http://www.wxpython.org/docs/api/wx.grid.Grid-class.html#DisableDragRowSize) is what you need.

Comment: documentation has moved: disable rows & cols https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.grid.Grid.html#wx.grid.Grid.DisableDragGridSize .. or to just deactivate one of the resize methods: DisableDragRowSize and DisableDragColSize are available